# JS спарсить значение из <script>window.runParams = {data: (в HTML странице)

Tags: javascript, html, парсер

Есть функция

```
function downloadHtml(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            // Remove image elements to prevent images loading
            //console.log(response);
            response = response.replace(/<img\b[^>]*>/ig, '');
            var dom = $.parseHTML(response);
            callback(dom);

        });
}
```

Которая получает ссылку на сайта и парсит с него данные. В HTML коде сайта есть кусок:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head><meta charset="utf-8"/>
...... куча-куча строк......
<script>
window.runParams = {data: {"actionModule":"addToCartUrl":"ddToShopcart4Js.htm","aeOrderFrom":"main_detail","allowVisitorAddCart":false,"categoryId":200003886,"companyId":230447385,
и так далее....
</body>
</html>
```

Стоит задача получить значение **categoryId** и **companyId**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let string = `{data: {"actionModule":"addToCartUrl":"ddToShopcart4Js.htm","aeOrderFrom":"main_detail","allowVisitorAddCart":false,"categoryId":200003886,"companyId":230447385,
    и так далее....   </body>  </html>`;
let pattern = /"categoryId":(\d+),/; // в скобках перебор чисел до запятой
let catId = string.match(pattern)[1]; // [0] - сама строка
```

Comment: На codepen все выводит. Закрыл отрывок кода тремя }}}

Comment: Прошу прощения, я видимо не так описал проблему. есть функция `function downloadHtml(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            // Remove image elements to prevent images loading
   //console.log(response);
   console.log(window.runParams.data['actionModule']['companyId']);
            response = response.replace(/<img\b[^>]*>/ig, '');
            var dom = $.parseHTML(response);
            callback(dom);
  
        });
}` в которая получает страницу HTML с куском кода выше.

Comment: Так какой должна быть структура HTML фрагмента для этих данных? Если необходимо получить только эти значения, то вставлять их можно куда угодно.

Comment: Переделайте вопрос, тут сложно разобраться

Comment: исправил вопрос

Comment: Понял теперь. Надо найти подстроку, а затем считать за ней другую подстроку до символа ','. Такой алгоритм пойдет?

Comment: Исправил ответ. Полностью не пишу. Сам принцип для categoryId.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/efimleonid/x7d1j0g5/19/